# embedded Nashorn - sandboxing execution

Tags: java, nashorn, scriptengine

I would like to get a clear answer on how to Sandbox execution Nashorn within a Java Application.

I have seen 'similar questions' (which I will refer to) but ultimately none of the answer seem to address my concerns.

Let me start with definitions.

Assume we start with this:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.put("map",new HashMap()); 
engine.eval(jsCode); // jsCode can access 'map' only.
```

By "Sandboxing" I mean ensure that the JavaScript must not access any java object except the one added in the scope.

so the following evals should be fine.

```
engine.eval("map.toString()"); 
engine.eval("map.size()"); 
engine.eval("map.put('name','jeff'); "); 
engine.eval("map.getClass()");
```

But the following evals will not:

```
engine.eval("var m = new java.util.HashMap();"); // <-- stop accessing Java
engine.eval("map.getClass().forName('java.io.File'); "); // stop. it's trying to be sneaky
```

Finally, I am not concerned about this:

```
engine.eval("while(1) {;}"); // this is impossible to detect. Maybe it's possible for this simple case... but sneaky users could make it impossible to detect... anyway this is not what I am asking. I am only concerned on accessing java objects.
```

So by sandboxing I intend to prevent jsCode to access java objects that I don't define.

I saw that this might be a potential solution:

```
jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new  jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(new jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ClassFilter() {

    public boolean exposeToScripts(String s) {
        return false;
    }

});
```

but is it 'safe' to access a package beginning with jdk.* directly ?

Another approach I saw is even more mysterious:

```
final ScriptEngine engine = 
   new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine(new String[] { "--no-java" });
```

I saw that one here:
[Safely re-using sandboxed Nashorn containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828426/safely-re-using-sandboxed-nashorn-containers)

**Can somebody let me know ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.* API if that would help in your application. javadoc for the same is here -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/

And yes, --no-java is the option for preventing java package access from script code.

Comment: but that "--no-java" is not documented officially. Certainly not in the javadoc.  Is it safe to do ?

Comment: @sundararajan any chance to tell me if '--no-java' will be supported in future versions or whether it is experimental only

Comment: strictly speaking only options displayed by jjs -help are supported options of jjs tool and nashorn. But, it is unlikely that options are removed just like that.

Comment: ok, many thanks then I won't use it. It feels like security concerns have not been properly addresed in nashorn.

Comment: I don't agree with that statement. Security concerns are addressed. If you run with SecurityManager, all scripts evaluated are in "sandbox". Only scripts loaded from specific URLs can be given permissions by your security policy. Class filtering is another topic - not related to security.

Comment: Please see also https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+script+security+permissions

Comment: In addition to running with security manager on, you can filter specific classes for scripts using ClassFilter ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ClassFilter.html ). Yes jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.* is published API.

Comment: Really thanks. What I meant to say is that security concerns are not officially addressed. I hate going directly to jdk.* packages. I had another question where I asked if I could access jdk.* and the answer was a unanimous "no". thanks for your help.